# Using class function from the lib directory in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a rails3 application and I want to create a class that handles string formatting, so I made a class called FormatUtilites.rb in the lib directory but whenever I try calling it from somewhere else in my app I get this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::FormatUtilities)`

So it thinks its a constant and not a class method, which is how it is defined. Any ideas?

```
class FormatUtilities

  def self.slugify(name)
    name.downcase.gsub(/\s|\W|\D/, "")
  end

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out rails3 stop autoloading the lib directory. I have no idea why they did it, but they did. Just needed to add it to the autoload in the application.rb

thanks anyways!

Comment: I don't think that it stopped autoloading. It's just that the name convention dictates, that a FormatUtilities class should be defined in file called format_utilities.rb rather than FormatUtilities.rb

Answer (score 1):

Classes are constants in Ruby, besides also being classes.  Probably you just need to do "require format_utilities"

Comment: but arent files from the lib directory supposed to autoload?

Comment: In my experience they don't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
# in config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths = %W(#{config.root}/lib
```

The name of your file should be format_utilities.rb for autoload to work.

In your particular case i would use a different aproach. Instead of creating a class with static functions i would create a module named FormattingHelper in app/helpers/formatting_helper.rb like this.

```
class FormattingHelper
  def slugify(name)
    name.downcase.gsub(/\s|\W|\D/, "")
  end
end
```

Then in ApplcationController or in a specific controller i would add:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :formatting
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rails to automatically load this file when it boots, you will need to name your file format_utilities.rb. The next time you restart your server or console, you should be able to do `FormatUtilities.slugify("name")`